# Keeping paragraphs justified when spilt between two page styles via a manual page break?

Tags: libreoffice, libreoffice-writer

In attempting to have separate topic headers within a chapter, I have used manual page breaks to change the page style. There are mirrored pages; and on the left-hand page is the Chapter number and title, and on the right-hand page the topic within the chapter. So, every time the topic title changes, there is a manual page break and a new page style.

It gets the desired headers, but I'm having trouble with the last row of text just before the manual page break. The paragraphs are justified; but after the insertion of the manual page break (that divides a paragraph between two page styles), the last row is no longer justified.

Is there a better method of handling this and one that will preserve the paragraphs when split between two page styles?

Thank you.

Comment: You can use Shift - Enter to add a blank line in a block of text without changing formatting. Do that prior to a break and formatting should be retained.

Comment: @John Thank you. That worked. The only downside is that the text prior to the break is one line short of the bottom but that happens frequently anyway due to orphan and widow records.

Comment: Gary, I really wonder which product you are talking about.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.